# Android layout priotity

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:visibility="invisible">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/video_playback_pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar_video"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/video_playback_pause" android:clickable=""/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now whe RelativeLayout and VideoView override.
the VideoView is show, and the RelativeLayout is hidden.
How to make the RelativeLayout on the top of VideoView?

Another problem is why the seekbar did not click?

I find that the priority of layout is decide by establish order?
But the problem of seekbar is still not resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/video_playback_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/video_playback_pause" android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

You can use the visibilty property as below

```
android:visibility="invisible" // invisible- just invisible the controls not the space
                               //gone - removes the allocated space too
                               //visible- shows the control
```

At run time also you can change

```
mylayout.setVisibilty(View.GONE)...
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the first part of question.
         
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
         
The inner relativeLayout's visibility is set to invisible.Remove it.

You have provided **android:clickable=""** for seekbar. May be thats why its not working. 
Remove that and try.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I just want to show the relativeLayout2 while the videoview is touch. So I initialit invisible.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to your seekbar, this could be the possible answer: Set

```
android:clickable="true"
```

and in your java code, try putting an Event Listener. For Event Listeners, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

When it comes to your layout, you can try using a Linear Layout and then nest a Relative Layout inside it. You might have to change your xml a bit.